Getting these make command errors while compiling an android kernel
──(root㉿kali)-[~/Documents/kernel-source-alioth-stock]
└─# make -j2 CC=clang O=output/ $config
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/Documents/kernel-source-alioth-stock/output'
....
HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
drivers/misc/Kconfig:587:warning: config symbol defined without type
drivers/misc/Kconfig:592:warning: config symbol defined without type
arch/arm64/configs/alioth_user_defconfig:768:warning: override: reassigning to symbol FW_CACHE
#
# configuration written to .config
#
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/Documents/kernel-source-alioth-stock/output'

──(root㉿kali)-[~/Documents/kernel-source-alioth-stock]
└─# make -j2 CC=clang O=output/
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/Documents/kernel-source-alioth-stock/output'                                                                                        
arch/arm64/Makefile:48: Detected assembler with broken .inst; disassembly will be unreliable                                                                           
  GEN     ./Makefile
.....
 HOSTLD  scripts/dtc/dtc
/usr/bin/ld: scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `yylloc'; scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:99: scripts/dtc/dtc] Error 1
make[2]: *** [../scripts/Makefile.build:642: scripts/dtc] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
/bin/sh: 1: bc: not found
make[2]: *** [.././Kbuild:42: include/generated/timeconst.h] Error 127
make[1]: *** [/root/Documents/kernel-source-alioth-stock/Makefile:1223: prepare0] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  HOSTLD  scripts/genksyms/genksyms
make[1]: *** [/root/Documents/kernel-source-alioth-stock/Makefile:1189: scripts] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/Documents/kernel-source-alioth-stock/output'
make: *** [Makefile:146: sub-make] Error 2

┌──(root㉿kali)-[~/Documents/kernel-source-alioth-stock]
└─#                                               

